# std::wstring присваивание == копирование

Tags: c++, строки, visual-c++

Если кратко описать вопрос то будет примерно так:

Шаблон `wstring` при присвоении ему значения, делает копирование, или он инициализирует новый объект и перезаписывает старые данные, именно при присваивании.
Т.е. данный код перезапишет значения, или выделит новую пямять под строку из кучи и сохранит новый указатель на строку?

```
class someclass
{
private:
    std::wstring m_str;
public:
    someclass()
    {
        m_str = std::wstring(L"Some old string");
        m_str = std::wstring(L"Some new string");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный код выполнит именно то, что вы написали: создаст независимый временный объект типа `std::wstring`, содержащий вашу строку, а затем сделает присваивание этого объекта в строку `m_str` при помощи *перемещающего* оператора присваивания.

Временный объект будет создаваться "с нуля", то есть в общем случае будет выделяться новая память из кучи (если не сработает какая-нибудь оптимизация, типа хранения коротких строк напрямую, без выделения в куче).

А перемещающий оператор присваивания можно реализовать разными способами. Это деталь реализации. Если строки хранятся без использования кучи (короткие строки), то перемещение сведется к копированию. Если все же использована куча, то можно сначала освободить старые данные, а потом выполнить перемещение из правой части путем перецепления указателей. А можно просто сделать `swap` полей объектов. И т.д. и т.п.

И так два раза.

А уж насколько компилятор умен и насколько сложно ему будет понять, что первое присваивание "не нужно", зависит еще от вороха дополнительных деталей (встроится ли код присваивания, знает ли компилятор семантику этого присваивания и т.д.)

Comment: А старый куда денется?

Comment: @Yami О каком именно "старом" идет речь?

Comment: тот что лежит в классе

Comment: удалится. Что же ему ещё делать

Comment: @KoVadim: т.е. выделяем память, удаляем старый объект, перемещаем копируем новый объект?

Comment: @Yami Он в вашем коде никуда на девается. Меняется только его содержимое при присваивании. Старое уничтожается, новое перемещается на его место. А как именно реализовано перемещающее присваивание - это уже деталь реализации. Можно просто swap сделать левой части с правой.

Comment: Возможно. А может память будет просто перетерта.

Comment: @KoVadim Что такое "удалится"? Объект `m_str` живет внутри объекта охватывющего класса и "удалиться" может только вместе с ним. Это вообще выходит за рамки вопроса.

Comment: я имел ввиду внутреннюю часть строки. Там все может быть по разному.